# Linq to search a property of a list based on string array variable

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `IQuerable` of `Gizmo`.

I want to write LINQ statement that will filter all Gizmos whose color is in the parameter (`string[]`) that I pass.

For example:

```
public class Gizmo
{
      public string Id { get; set; }

      public string Name { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<Color> Colors { get; set; } = new List<Color>();
}

public class Color
{
      public string Id { get; set; }
      public string Value { get; set; } 
}
```

I will be supplied a parameter like:

```
var filterColors = new[] { "red", "silver" };
```

I want to write something similar to:

```
gizmos = gizmos.Where(x => x.ColorTags.Contains(filterColors));
```

Comment: Okay, so you wrote it, what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for:

```
gizmos = gizmos.Where(x => filterColors.Any(z => x.Colors.Any(e => e.Value == z)));
```